# Python SMTP Function Issue

Tags: python, function, smtplib

I have a python script sending emails via a Gmail SMTP setup shown below which works fine.  However when I try to turn this into a function it no longer sends any emails.  Any help you can give me would be appreciated.

```
import smtplib

SMTP_SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com'
SMTP_PORT = 587

sender = 'account@gmail.com'
password = 'password'
recipient = ['user@Email1.com', 'user@Email2.com']
subject = 'Gmail SMTP Test'
body = 'blah blah blah'

body = "" + body + ""

headers = ["From: " + sender,
       "Subject: " + subject,
       "To: " + ", " .join(recipient),
       "MIME-Version: 1.0",
       "Content-Type: text/html"]
headers = "\r\n".join(headers)

session = smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT)

session.ehlo()
session.starttls()
session.ehlo
session.login(sender, password)

session.sendmail(sender, recipient, headers + "\r\n\r\n" + body)
session.quit()
```

If I try to wrap this into a function it no longer sends an email.  I have tried several diffrent varaiations on the def SendEmail() with no luck.

```
import smtplib

def SendEmail(self): 
    SMTP_SERVER = 'account.gmail.com'
    SMTP_PORT = 587

    sender = 'account@gmail.com'
    password = 'Password'
    recipient = ['user@Email1.com', 'user@Email2.com']
    subject = 'Gmail SMTP Test'
    body = 'blah blah blah'

    body = "" + body + ""

    headers = ["From: " + sender,
           "Subject: " + subject,
           "To: " + ", " .join(recipient),
           "MIME-Version: 1.0",
           "Content-Type: text/html"]
    headers = "\r\n".join(headers)

    session = smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT)

    session.ehlo()
    session.starttls()
    session.ehlo
    session.login(sender, password)

    session.sendmail(sender, recipient, headers + "\r\n\r\n" + body)
    session.quit()
```

Comment: Isn't `SMTP_SERVER` supposed to be `smtp.gmail.com`?

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to call a function. Plus, you don't need `self` argument:

```
import smtplib

def SendEmail():
    SMTP_SERVER = 'account.gmail.com'
    SMTP_PORT = 587

    sender = 'account@gmail.com'
    password = 'Password'
    recipient = ['user@Email1.com', 'user@Email2.com']
    subject = 'Gmail SMTP Test'
    body = 'blah blah blah'

    body = "" + body + ""

    headers = ["From: " + sender,
           "Subject: " + subject,
           "To: " + ", " .join(recipient),
           "MIME-Version: 1.0",
           "Content-Type: text/html"]
    headers = "\r\n".join(headers)

    session = smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT)

    session.ehlo()
    session.starttls()
    session.ehlo
    session.login(sender, password)

    session.sendmail(sender, recipient, headers + "\r\n\r\n" + body)
    session.quit()

SendEmail()
```

Also, it might be a good idea to move your constants like `SMTP_SERVER` in a separate config file or just move outside of the function. Plus, it would look nicer if you'll pass `recipient`, `subject`, `body` variables as function arguments instead of hardcoding them inside the function.

Also, this `session.ehlo` (no parenthesis) line does nothing.